# How to use the result from a Yes/No MessageBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, messagebox

I'm trying to make a program which reserves and shows available and unavailable seats for an "event".  The errors I'm getting are as follows:

> 'System.Nullable' does not contain a definition for 'Yes' and no extension method 'Yes' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Nullable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

(Same goes for "No") and

> 'System.Windows.Window.DialogResult' is a 'property' but is used like a 'type'.

This is what I have so far:

```
private void btnSeat1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!Seat1)
    {
        DialogResult Result = MessageBox.Show("This Seat is Available, Would you like to pick it?", "Would you like this seat?", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question);

        if (Result == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You Reserved this seat");
            btnSeat1.Text = "Reserved";
        }
        else if (Result == DialogResult.No)
        {
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
```

Note: I only used Environment.Exit as a placeholder. It was intentional and will be changed accordingly. It isn't the source of the problem.

Comment: What specifically isn't working in this code?

Comment: Do you really want to exit the program if the user selects "no"?

Comment: You say your code isn't working--so what is it doing wrong?  And why are you using Environment.Exit()?  That should be for aborting your application--which sounds pretty counter to what you would intend.

Comment: Yes, you should instead use a `return;` statement.

Comment: I only used Environment.Exit(0) as a placeholder. That was intentional

Comment: It looks like the class this method is in contains a property which is called DialogResult

Comment: I've edited your post to make it a little clearer - feel free to revert anything that isn't right.  Also, I removed this sentence as it's an entirely different question and should probably be asked separately if you still have issues: _"Also, How can I change the text in a button to whatever is in the associated text box, when clicked?"_

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This line:

```
DialogResult Result = MessageBox.Show("This Seat is Available, Would you like to pick it?", "Would you like this seat?", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question);
```

Should actually be this:

```
var Result = MessageBox.Show("This Seat is Available, Would you like to pick it?", "Would you like this seat?", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question);
```

And then if you hover over `Result` you can see its not of a `DialogResult`, but a `MessageBoxResult`, or, if you prefer to explicitly type it, try:

```
MessageBoxResult Result = MessageBox.Show(...
```

So you would use it like this in your if statements:

```
if (Result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
{
    MessageBox.Show("You Reserved this seat");
    btnSeat1.Text = "Reserved";
}
else if (Result == MessageBoxResult.No)
{
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

You are getting the error because `DialogResult` is actually a property of the `Window` class, and you are trying to use it like its a type (as the compiler says).

Comment: Thanks Hans, I had to make another change but you are right, WPF not Winforms.

Comment: Thank you! Really appreciate the feedback!:)

Comment: Use `DialogResult` if your application is a `WinForms` application. Use `MessageBoxResult` if your application is a `WPF/Silverlight` application. `Namespaces are different`: System.Windows.Forms (Winforms) vs System.Windows (WPF)